# Regex patterns for validation

Tags: java, regex

I want to use `regex` pattern for validation,

1. regex for allowing  `only alphabets and space only`

   for this am using `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]+$` but its not validating correctly.
2. regex for allowing `all aplhabets,numbers except special characters`.

Anyone can help me, with this `two` regex patterns ?

Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with some examples of matching and failing text for each pattern. It will help.

Comment: Is empty string ok or should there be one or more chars in the string? Any other length requirements?

Comment: "is not validating correctly" - What is it not validating correctly?

Comment: Define special characters. Do you mean those beautiful letters like e.g. "äöüßèéô"?

Comment: Which alphabets do you mean when you say "all alphabets"? Isn't English alphabet enough? Why explicitly exclude special characters? Does any of the alphabets you're working with include them?

Comment: @stema really ??not that kind of letters

Comment: @AdamZalcman "all alphabets" means englishhhh alphabets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `^[a-zA-Z\s]+$` (if you want all white spaces, like tabs, etc.)

   or `^[a-zA-Z ]+$` (if you want only "normal" spaces)
2. `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: A bit harsh. It is a valid regexp. It's not valid if you put it in a string, that's all. The link I copied contains the official list of all accepted constructs for Java regexp. And nothing was said about not validating a space (or it was poorly said).

Comment: I made a test project with two `EditText` (regex pattern & str) and a button for checking str against the pattern. It's working perfectly with these strings.

Answer (score 2):

Regex 1 (letters and space only) :

```
"^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$"
```

Regex 2 (match all letters, all numbers and underscore)

```
"^\\w+$"
```

Comment: its working fine, but i want only for all letters, all numbers no underscore..what shld i change